# My location is not refresh even if I set the .interval on Location request

Tags: android, location-services, google-location-services

```
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
private double currentLatitude;
private double currentLongitude;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

Button btn_start;
TextView txt_refersh;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);


    btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    txt_refersh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_refersh);


    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.e("currentLatitude", "" + currentLatitude);
            Log.e("currentLongitude", "" + currentLongitude);



        }
    });


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds





}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    System.runFinalization();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    System.gc();
    Log.e("System GC", "Called");


    super.onResume();


    //Now lets connect to the API
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }


    super.onPause();
    Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onPause()");


}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    } else {
        //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();


        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(60000);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        getLocationdetails(getApplicationContext());
        Log.e("currentLatitude", "" + currentLatitude);
        Log.e("currentLongitude", "" + currentLongitude);



    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
        Log.e("Error", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

/**
 * If locationChanges change lat and long
 *
 * @param location
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
}

private Location getLocationdetails(Context context) {

    Location location = null;

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return null;


        } else {
            Log.e("currentLatitude", "" + currentLatitude);
            Log.e("currentLongitude", "" + currentLongitude);



            location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        }


    }


    return location;
}
```

I use locationRequest.setInterval (60000); for refreshing my location but it is still not refreshing. What should I do more to get the current Latitude and Longitude every after 10 mins. I just wanted to get the log of lat long every after 10 mins.

Comment: Did you implements LocationListener in you class?

If you implements LocationListener, it is automatically update the location in onLocationChanged(Location location) method.

Comment: I used Following code for refreshing the location :-         LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(6000);

Comment: Please update the complete code, this code doesn't has the class name.

Comment: yes I implements  Location Listener . I dont wont to update location only when i change the position . I want to get Lat long on every 10 mins even if i am in the same place.

Comment: If you are in same place you lat & long will not change. It must be same lat & long only.

Comment: I wanted to send that lat long in Backend every time after 10 min wheather it is same or it is different. How can i do this.?

Comment: Better you can store the lat & long in class variable, when location change, you can update the class variables. When you need, you can use the class variables. And you can send the values to back end also.